# Cannot detect association_proxy.rb in Rails 4.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `composite_primary_keys` gem with Rails 4.0.0.rc1. After adding to Gemfile

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
```

and run bundle install, I add

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'
```

to `application.rb`. However, when I run `rails generate create_table`, I got the following error:

```
  /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': 
 cannot load such file -- active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/composite_primary_keys-3.1.6/lib/composite_primary_keys.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/name/idme/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `require'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

I checked `composite_primary_keys.rb` file in this gem, and found that it required `association_proxy.rb`. However, it seems that Rails couldn't find this file.

Did I require this gem at the wrong time vis-a-vis Rails loading order? Or is this because association_proxy.rb is no longer in Rails 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem with the difference of using

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys', '=3.1.0'
```

fixed it by scratching the version and running

```
bundle update composite_primary_keys
```

Trying a different version might help.